# Apply Composite Aggregation on Filtered data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using "Composite Aggregation" as my use case requires "Pagination" on buckets returned by Aggregation, as the number of returned buckets could be huge.

I also need to run "Composite aggregation" on a specific time range, I'm using a "range" filter for this. However, the response from elasticsearch does not contain any data in "aggregations". "hits" array does contain proper data as per filter. I'm only interested in the result of "Composite Aggregation".

Am I missing something?

**Request is as below :**

```
GET <my-index>/_search 
{
  "query" : {
    "range" : {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "gte" : "2020-03-29T14:53:42.068Z",
        "lt" : "2020-03-29T15:53:42.068Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "uniq_userids": {
      "composite" : {
        "size": 100,
        "sources" : [
          { "by_userid": { "terms" : { "field": "userid.keyword" } } }
        ]
      }
    } 
  } 
}
```

**Response is as below :**

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 12,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
          ...
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "uniq_userids" : {
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected output in aggregations element**

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "uniq_userids" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "by_userid" : "user4"
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "by_userid" : "user1"
          },
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "by_userid" : "user2"
          },
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "by_userid" : "user3"
          },
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**Example of a document**

```
      {
        "_index": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "fpFcKXEB9-HOO02nOoEG",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "message": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
          "input": {
            "type": "log"
          },
          "tags": [
            "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
          ],
          "offset": 56422597,
          "logday": "2020-03-29",
          "userid": "user1",
          "source": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
          "@version": "1",
          "prospector": {
            "type": "log"
          },
          "Micro_time": "2020-03-29 14:54:01.366719",
          "logtime": "14:54:01.366719",
          "@timestamp": "2020-03-29T14:54:01.366Z"
        }
      }
```

Comment: { "from":"2020-03-29T14:00:00.000Z" "to":"2020-03-29T14:00:00.000Z" }  --->both the dates are same , is it correct. Can you add sample data which should come in aggregation result

Comment: Shouldn't time filtering be in query?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal, Thanks for pointing out. I pasted a wrong query which I tried earlier. I have corrected it now. Please refer to the corrected query in the post. I have pasted the expected value of aggregation as well.  Thanks !

Comment: @Johnny, Thanks for poiiting out. It was a typo. Have corrected it now.

Comment: @codeseeker can you add document where timestamp between 2020-03-29T14:53:42.068Z and 2020-03-29T15:53:42.068Z Your query looks fine. Need document as it could be timezone issue. also can you add your mapping

Comment: Looks correct, make sure your `userid` has a keyword type.

Comment: @Johnny, I used "userid.keyword" as value for "field" in "terms" aggregation

Comment: @jaspreetchahal, I have added an example of a document

Comment: add your mapping

Comment: I tried with your document result is appearing in aggregation . I think userid.keyword doesn't exist , check your mapping

Comment: I debugged again. The issue was in logstash patterns file. Grok pattern initially was storing userid in "usrid" field. The data for 2020-03-29 was created with this field. Later I updated "usrid" to "userid" in Grok patterns and updated ES query as well to "userid". Since 2020-03-29 data had no "userid", no data was returned by ES in response.

Thanks for your time jaspreet, Johnny !